# Python 3.4.3 Asteroid Statistic Generator Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, syntax, syntax-error

I am working on a program in python 3.4.3 that generates random asteroid statistics. I want it to generate a random name, type, and surface gravity.

Examples:

MUS-983 A Type Surface Gravity: 0.31 m/s²

The code I have so far is:
`import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.choice(['A Type','B Type','C Type'])])+"Surface Gravity: "+"".join([random.randint(0.01, 0.39)]))`

Which has worked well until i put in the part about Surface gravity on the end. Now I have a few questions. First is when I run the program i get a error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pick(1)
  File "/Users/James/Desktop/Asteroid Name Generator.py", line 4, in pick
    print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.choice(['A Type','B Type','C Type'])])+" "+"".join([random.randint(0.01, 0.39)]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 218, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 182, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()`

The second question is how to integrate the 'm/s²' title in front of the randomly generated surface gravity decimal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are giving random.randint() floating point parameters.  Try changing:

```
random.randint(0.01, 0.39)
```

to:

```
float(random.randint(1, 39))/100.0
```

edit :
Okay it needs that converted back to a string, let's use string formatting to make things a little prettier:

```
"Surface Gravity: %f.2 m/s2"%(float(random.randint(1, 39))/100.0)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pick(1)
  File "/Users/James/Desktop/Asteroid Name Generator.py", line 4, in pick
    print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.choice(['A Type (Small)','B Type (Medium)','C Type (large)','D Type (Huge)'])])+" "+"".join([float(random.randint(1, 39))/100.0]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @user2368535 just need to convert that back to a string.  I updated my answer and used some string formatting to de-clutter things a little.